# raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled " ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have two csv files as 1.csv and 2.csv. 1.csv has 50 lines and 2. csv has 75 lines.

Now i am trying to write to a new csv file that is 3.csv based on matching username, feature, ipaddress.

i tried my code but it is giving the above error.

Any help would be appreciated.

below is the code that i have tried.

```
df1.to_csv('1.csv')
df2.to_csv('2.csv')
with open('1.csv') as a:
    c=pd.read_csv(a)
    with open('2.csv') as b:
        d=pd.read_csv(b)
        if (c['User'] == d['User'] and c['Feature'] == d['Feature'] and c['ipaddress'] == d['ipaddress']):
          c['User']=c['user']
          c['Feature']=c['Feature']
          c['ipaddress']=c['ipaddress']
          c.to_csv('3.csv')
```

Comment: Please include the traceback of your error so we can see at which line this error occurs.

Comment: raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: at this line if (c['User'] == d['User'] and c['Feature'] == d['Feature'] and c['ipaddress'] == d['ipaddress']):

Comment: Please copy and paste the *full* traceback *into your question*. It's not easy to read in the comments.

Comment: hi, below is the error that i am getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pathtomainpythonfile/main.py", line 181, in <module>
    if (c['User'] == d['User'] and c['Feature'] == d['Feature'] and c['ipaddress'] == d['ipaddress']):
  File "c-drivepath\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1190, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: please suggest me any solution

Comment: Can you define "matching"? Because your dataframes are of different lengths (and different labels, as suggested in the error), a column-to-column comparison is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input. but how to define matching